# Drawing Text on a Canvas in a loop

Tags: java, android, canvas, png

I have a long string which I am sure will not fit on the image. So I ended up calculating lines and then writing line by line on the `Bitmap` using a `Canvas`. The problem is only the first line gets written. I will always be writing on this one image. The length of each line is fixed at 40 characters. Please check the code below:

```
private Bitmap prepareImageWithText(String text){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.text_image); // Load your bitmap here
        Bitmap aBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); // copy the bitmap because the one from the Resources is immutable.
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(aBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(75);

        for(int i=0; i<calculateLines(text); i++) {
            int beginFrom = i*40;
            int endAt = beginFrom + 40;
            if(endAt > text.length()){
                endAt = text.length()-1;
            }
            String writableArea = text.substring(beginFrom, endAt);
            canvas.drawText(writableArea, 100, 300+(i*100), paint);
            canvas.save();
        }
        return aBitmap;
    }

   private int calculateLines(String text){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
            int lines = text.length()/40;
            return lines;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: simply use `android.text.Layout`

Comment: @pskink Can you explain?

Comment: use it to draw your looong text on the `Canvas`, no need for `"calculating lines and then writing line by line"`, instead just create a `Layout` instance and `draw` it on your `Canvas`

Comment: Ahh!!! I just want to understand how to do it directly on a bitmap, any suggestions to how to get this piece working. Although I would try your approach as well, I really want to understand doing it using the approach in the question. Also could you please enlighten on what are the possible performance issues using this approach viz. a viz. the Layout approach.

Comment: you are breaking your text on 40 character long chunks (not paying any attention on the actual text width in pixels) and not breaking your text on "white space"  characters like space or tab symbol, this is not how text should be divided into several lines

Comment: You should use `Math.roof(quote.lenth()/40f)` instead of using integer calculation which would give you incorrect values.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake `Math.roof`? what `roof` are you talking about? even if it was `Math.ceil`, what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Yes, its `ceil()`. If you have anything less than 80 characters you line count would be 1.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake ah ok, i missed that he is using `i<calculateLines(text)` and not `i<=calculateLines(text)`

Comment: @pskink that was really it. Such a noob mistake, did not realize that was the problem. I will obviously work on the word based approach rather than the character based approach.

Comment: just use `Layout` it takes only two lines of safe code and not dozens...

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<calculateLines(quote); i++) {
```

and

```
if(endAt > text.length()){
```

These two lines need your attention. Is the "text" and "quote" the same String?

Comment: they are the same thing, just a formatting error. I think I have fixed this as of now.

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs that is not a formatting error. You need to explain your problem, otherwise it is unwise from our part to try to help you.

Comment: Really sorry for the confusion, I have corrected the variable names all across. But the real problem was incorrect calculation of number of iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `quote` to `calculateLines` and you are only doing anything if it is not empty, yet, you use `mQuote`'s `length` there. I think this confusion is the cause of your problem. You need to make sure that the value you pass is the one you want to pass and use the `length` of `quote` in your calculation instead of `mQuote`'s `length`.

Comment: mQuote and quote are the same. just a formatting error.

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs what is quote, how is it initialized, what is its value when the method is being called?

Comment: prepareImageWithText(String text), receives text as an input. and calls on calculateLines() receives this as an input.

Comment: @Ichthyocentaurs calculateLines receives quote as the input, prepareImageWithText does not pass its parameter text to it. Please, edit your question with your real code if you want any help.